# How to set value of an agent variable same as the value of another variable of same agent in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to assign value of an agent variable based on the value of another variable of the same agent in NetLogo.
In my model agents have two variables one is "my-batches" and and another one is "my-targets". At every time-step agent tries to find targets to place their batches according to a range of criteria. At initialization, the value of 'my-batches' is randomly assigned (ranging between 0 -15). How should I code so that agents find the same number of "my-targets" as their "my-batches"? I am trying something like

```
turtles-own [my-batches my-targets distance-travelled ] 
patches-own [roads? target-cell? resource]

to setup   
ca
crt num-turtles

ask turtles [
    set my-batches random 15  
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set distance-travelled 0     ; initial travel distance is zero   ]

ask patches [      
    set resource random 9    
    ifelse resource = 0    
       [ set target-cell? false]  [ set target-cell? true ]
reset-ticks 
end

to go  
if ticks > 365 [ stop ]   
find-my-targets  
calculate-distance    
tick  
end 

to find-my-targets

**if target-cell? false [ ask turtles [ set my-targets [ n-of [ my-batches ] of myself ] ]]**

end
```

Any help with this?

Also, can  anyone  provide suggestions for example model to calculate cumulative distance travelled by agents (from start point to end point)?

Answer (score 0):

The `find-my-targets` procedure is, at the moment, a procedure executed by the observer. So you first have to use `ask turtles`; or, alternatively, make the procedure be executed by turtles. Using the second approach (which is more consistent with the name of the procedure), it would be:

```
to go
  if ticks > 365 [ stop ]
  ask turtles [
    find-my-targets
    calculate-distance
  ]
  tick
end

to find-my-targets
  if (not target-cell?) [
    set my-targets n-of my-batches patches
  ]
end
```

This leaves a couple of doubts:

- Do you want `my-targets` to be any patches or only patches that are target cells? If the latter, then you should do `set my-targets n-of (my-batches) (patches with [target-cell?])` (parentheses only used for readability).
- Do you want to have `my-targets` being reset every time a turtle is on a patch that is not a target cell? Because that is what is happening right now, just pointing it out...

---

As for the distance question (which really should be a separate question), just use the `distancexy` primitive in this way (you didn't say how your turtles move, so I will invent it):

```
to move-and-calculate-distance
  let startingx xcor
  let startingy ycor

  move-to one-of my-targets

  let last-distance-travelled (distancexy startingx startingy)
  set distance-travelled (distance-travelled + last-distance-travelled)
end
```

---

PS: note that `random 15` gives an integer in the 0-14 interval. If you want `my-batches` to be an integer between 0 and 15, use `random 16`.